# what's the difference between an ico file and a png icon file

Tags: wpf, winforms

For windows programming, can I use PNG file as icon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

An ICO is actually a specialized file format that contains a collection of images at potentially many different sizes and color depths.  A png is a specific image.

What you *can* do is create an .ico from a .png.  I've found [IconMaker](http://www.inedo.com/downloads/icon-maker) convenient for that purpose.

Comment: IconMaker - Page not found

Answer (score 1):

Well, the difference is that they are different file formats :-).

As to using them as icons on MS Windows:

Only Vista supports PNG icons out of the box; for earlier Windows versions, you will have to use .ico files. There are however many converter programs. So your best bet probably is to internally store icons as PNG during development (as it is a superior format), then convert the icon to .ico during your application's build process.